# How to specify Maven plugin property from command line if "property" is not set?

Tags: java, maven

This is how my Maven plugin looks:

```
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;

@Mojo(name = "my", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
  @Parameter
  protected String foo;
  // the rest of the code skipped
}
```

I can call it form command line:

```
$ mvn my:my
```

But I don't know how to set `foo` [using](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html) `-D`. What is the right way to specify it from the command line *without* adding `property` attribute to the [`@Parameter`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Parameter.html) annotation?

Comment: What restricts you from specifying the `property` value in the `@Parameter` annotation?

Comment: In my real situation, it's not my plugin and I can't change its code. I'm just trying to find a way to provide a parameter to it from the command line.

Comment: Please state the plugin. This is only possible if the plugins defined it's parameter with `User property is:..` but anyway I can only guess because I don't know which plugin you are talking about...

Comment: It's [compiler:compile](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) mojo I'm trying to configure. I'm trying to set `compileSourceRoots` property.